# Better understanding of Angular error

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

I am trying out angular and I am stuck on understanding the error, which means if I cannot understand error I cannot move forward e.g.

> zone.js:654 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load product-list.component.html ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load product-list.component.html

I am totally unaware of what this error means. Should be there any glossary on the angular website to help better understand the errors? While looking at zone.js It is too hard for a novice javascript developer to understand.

Comment: Check ./product-list.component.html exists and in the same folder as the class

Comment: It does, Shouldn't it highlight if it doesn't. What does /. means? as I got a products folder and inside it are files.

Comment: no, it doesn' higlight for the decorator

Comment: ./ means the same folder. Try to remove. You confirm that you have two files app/products/product-list.component.html and product-list.component.ts ?

Comment: yes both under products folder @Vega

Comment: Didn't help @Vega

Comment: Did you start with the newest version of the files from my github? I updated the course last week to use Angular CLI, Webpack, and Angular 4.3. Or are you using older files that still use systemjs?

Comment: @DeborahK it says under info "Tuesday, 16 May 2017 at 13:59". I think I am on the old one?

Comment: Are you able to get more current code that matches with the current version of the course?

Comment: @DeborahK As the question wasn't regarded as useful, I have rephased the question. Would be helpful if you can put in your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'pm-app',
    ....
}

and 

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'pm-products',
   ....
}
```

Comment: Can u be more elaborate of where should I use these as I am new to angular

Comment: Just add this line : moduleId: module.id, inside your components decorators, on top of everything. On both! You see?

Comment: This is only needed if he is using systemjs. If he is using the Angular CLI, it handles relative paths automatically.

Comment: @DeborahK I am using, Getting Started with Angular, out of APM-update folder.

Comment: @Vega no, I did your change but got more errors then before. I tried using just `template` instead of `templateUrl` and that worked. Seem like it is not picking up the template.

Comment: Those were replaced last Thursday (August 10th). Can you download and use the new ones here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted

Comment: The older files don't support relative paths. So you either need to use Vega's suggestion, OR change the file paths to absolute paths, OR download and use the newer code. Be sure to delete your node_modules and re-run `npm install` with the new files.